# full calendar Jquery, Auto Insert Events in to the calender

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

```
var events;
events = events + "{title:'"+$("#txtEventName").val()+"',start:'2011-04-20',end:'2011-04-21',allDay:false}"

calender.fullcalendar({
   events[
          the variable here,
    ]
});
```

so i want to insert this variable into the full calendar "events", i want to know is this possible to do it ??

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var curEvents = [];
curEvents.push({
 title: $("#txtEventName").val(),
 start:'2011-04-20',
 end:'2011-04-21',
 allDay:false
});

calender.fullcalendar({
   events: curEvents
});
```